# Link List - no operator '<<' matches

Tags: c++

My c++ is really poor. Anyhow with the code snippet bellow why do I get a error on the << in the do while loop when outside of it I get no error. The error is: no operator "<<" matches these operands. However the string w picks up the word fine. I read somewhere I may have to overload it but why? And how would I over load it for a link list.
Thanks in advance.

```
void print()
{
 HashTable *marker = headOne;
 HashTable *inList;
 for( int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++ )
 {
    cout << i << ": " << marker->number << endl;
    if(marker->child != NULL)
    {
        inList = marker;
        do
        {
            string w = inList->word; 
            cout << w << endl;
            inList = inList->child;
        }
        while(inList != NULL);  
    }
    marker = marker->next;
 }//end for loop
}
```

Comment: You need the HashTable definition and declarations for headOne and tableSize. I guessed at those things and it compiles for me so the problem is probably in the missing parts. Also show your includes and using statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to `cout` a `std::string` you have to include:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: I was using string.h instead I think it was.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
// Missing includes and using
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// missing struct
struct HashTable {
    HashTable* next;
    HashTable* child;
    string word;
    int number;
};

// missing vars
HashTable ht;
HashTable* headOne = &ht;
int tableSize = 5;

// Unchanged
void print()
{
 HashTable *marker = headOne;
 HashTable *inList;
 for( int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++ )
 {
    cout << i << ": " << marker -> number << endl;
    if(marker->child != NULL)
    {
        inList = marker;
        do
        {
            string w = inList -> word; 
            cout << w << endl;
            inList = inList -> child;
        }
        while(inList != NULL);  
    }
    marker = marker -> next;
 }//end for loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I read somewhere I may have to overload it but why?

Because there's no overload that matches your need.

> And how would I over load it for a link list.

You can do this outside of your class or struct:
(where `T` is the type of the object that you want to print)

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& obj)
{
  /* write obj to stream */
  return os;
}
```

This is just an example that prints a vector:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, vector<int>& obj)
{
  for (auto &i : obj)
    os << i << " ";
  return os;
}
```

Then I would be able to simply do this `cout << n.vec;` where `n` is the class object and `vec` the name of a vector of ints.